# Getting custom iFrame from a different url to display in a Facebook Page Tab

Tags: facebook

I am trying to get a widget that is inside an iframe to install as a facebook page tab. The way it is set up now is the user can customize the widget, then when they have done that a button appears that directs them to the "Add Page Tab" page. The widget url for the widget they have customized is added to the end of the url so:

```
    https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=MY_APP_ID&next=CUSTOMIZED_WIDGET_URL
```

The problem I am running into is this: Once the user clicks to "Add Page Tab", it just goes to that widget url and not to the page tab with the url contents displayed inside that iframe. A page tab is added to the test page I have but it does not display what I want it to and I will get to that later. I have looked at some other widgets that do what I want and they redirect from that "Add Page Tab" page to the actual page tab with their customized widget in the iframe there.

I am also unsure of what I should have the Page Tab url set to in my app settings considering that the url for the widget will change from user to user. If I set the Page Tab to a specific url, it of course shows that url in the iframe after I have done the "Add Page Tab" and doesn't show my widget.

I have tried looking for a tutorial on this but I can't seem to find any. Please let me know if I need to clarify any of this. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want the user to be redirected to the page where the tab app was installed?

Comment: I want the user to be redirected to the actual page tab that is installed on their page

Comment: Well you'll need to generate the dialog URL for each user... Tab app urls look like this - `https://www.facebook.com/{PAGE_NAME}/app_{APP_ID}`.

Comment: With regard to the Page Tab url, you should provide it with the default landing page for the application. Once the application is loaded on the page, you can take a look at the signed_request and determine (according to the page_id) what customized content you want to display.

Comment: And this will redirect the user after they have clicked the "Add to Page" button to the page tab on their page? Sorry if I am not understanding correctly.

Comment: Yes - the `next` parameter in the url is where the user will be redirected after they finish with the add app to page dialog.

Comment: So after reading some documentation and taking into account what you have advised, will the end url for the user look something like this then? `https://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_AppId&app_data=any_string_here` If so, will that app_data string be added to the end of the Page Tab url that I have specificed in my app settings? I appreciate your help

Comment: That won't work because the tab url for each page needs to be the same  - there is only one field in the application settings. You'll have to inspect the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/). From that you'll be able to know what page is requesting the application and you can show appropriate content.